# Fetching values (multiline) of a term and store in a variable in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python so apologies if it is a basic query. I would like to save values of ENTRY, NAME, SYMBOL, AND PATHWAY in their respective variables, whereever it is available. I am having issue while saving the values if it is followed by a space. How can I get that information.

ENTRY variable should have '102724788         CDS       T01001'. PATHWAY should have both the lines.

```
ENTRY       102724788         CDS       T01001
NAME        (RefSeq) proline dehydrogenase 1, mitochondrial
SYMBOL      ARVBSH8
ORTHOLOGY   K00318  proline dehydrogenase [EC:1.5.5.2]
ORGANISM    hsa  Homo sapiens (human)
PATHWAY     hsa00330  Arginine and proline metabolism
            hsa01100  Metabolic pathways
BRITE       KEGG Orthology (KO) [BR:hsa00001]
             09100 Metabolism
              09105 Amino acid metabolism
               00330 Arginine and proline metabolism
                102724788
            Enzymes [BR:hsa01000]
             1. Oxidoreductases
              1.5  Acting on the CH-NH group of donors
               1.5.5  With a quinone or similar compound as acceptor
                1.5.5.2  proline dehydrogenase
                 102724788
POSITION    22
MOTIF       Pfam: Pro_dh HrpB2
DBLINKS     NCBI-GeneID: 102724788
            NCBI-ProteinID: NP_001355178
            Ensembl: ENSG00000277196
///
ENTRY       112268355         CDS       T01001
NAME        (RefSeq) killer cell immunoglobulin-like receptor 3DS1-like
ORGANISM    hsa  Homo sapiens (human)
POSITION    19
MOTIF       Pfam: ig Ig_2 Ig_3
DBLINKS     NCBI-GeneID: 112268355
            NCBI-ProteinID: NP_001355183
///
```

Comment: You have to be more clear about how it is being input, isit stored as a string in many lines or isit already processed into a dict?

Comment: As a Dictionary. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {}
isPathway = false

for line in reader.lines():
    line_list = line.split(" ")    #makes a list of the line
    if isPathway = true:
        data['PATHWAY'] += " ".join(line_list)
        isPathway = false
    elif 'PATHWAY' in line:
        data['PATHWAY'] = " ".join(line_list[1:])
        isPathway = true
    ...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).